# Почему в список быстрей добавляются элементы нежели в массив?

Tags: массивы, list, список, vector, вектор

[image: Доступ ко 3 элементу массива]

[image: Доступ к 3 элементу списка]
Почему доступ к элементам у вектора быстрей чем у списка это понятно, да и почему добавлять в вектор новый элемент затратно тоже понятно, ведь нужно подвинуть следующие элементы.Но почему добавлять в список новые элементы менее затратно, ведь здесь также нужно отодвинуть следующие элементы или я не прав?Пожалуйста помогите разобраться , был бы очень признателен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не вполне верная картинка для списка.

Элементы в списке не обязательно идут подряд. Наоборот, за счёт того, что каждый элемент имеет указатель на следующий элемент, элементы списка могут идти **не подряд**.

Поэтому для добавления элемента в любое место списка — например, за элементом E — нужно лишь переставить указатель на следующий элемент у E, а сдедующим элементом нового элемента сделать тот элемент, который раньше был следующим элементом для E. Сами элементы двигать не надо.

А для добавления в вектор нужно передвинуть в памяти все элементы, начиная с E.